# Distribution of Poisson process with waiting time.

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let $X,Y$ two independent Poisson processes with parameters $\lambda, \mu$ and $T=\inf\{t\geq 0 \mid Y(t)=1\}$. Calculate $P(X(T/2)=k)$ with $k=0,1, \ldots$.

---

What I've tried is

By law of total probability
\begin{align}
P\left(X \Bigl(\frac{T}{2}\Bigr)=k\right)&=\int_0^\infty P\bigl(X(t/2)=k \mid T=t \bigr)P(T=t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda^k t^k e^{-\lambda t/2}}{2^{k}k!}\mu e^{-\mu t} \,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{\lambda^k}{2^{k}(\lambda/2+\mu)^{k+1}}
\end{align}

but I don't know if I'm using well the total probability law and the fact that the waiting times has Beta distribution (in this case the waiting time is the first, then is exponentially distributed).

Thanks for the advices.

Comment: I didn't check your final step of anti-derivative computation, but your first line (setting the integral) looks correct to me. What specific doubt do you have?

Comment: Thanks, my question was: if the first is correct?. I have a mistake in the last line I was missing a factor $\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is mostly correct, but you are missing a factor of $\mu$; i.e., $$\begin{align}\Pr[X(T/2) = k] &= \frac{\mu \lambda^k}{2^k (\lambda/2 + \mu)^{k+1}} \\
&= \frac{2\mu}{\lambda} \left(1 + \frac{2\mu}{\lambda}\right)^{-(k+1)} \\
&= \frac{2\mu}{2\mu + \lambda} \left(1 - \frac{2\mu}{2\mu+\lambda}\right)^k, \quad k \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}.
\end{align}$$
When written this way, it becomes obvious that $X(T/2)$ is geometric with parameter $$\theta = \frac{2\mu}{2\mu + \lambda} = \frac{\mu}{\mu + \lambda/2}.$$

Comment: Thak you very much. Yeah, I forgot the the $\mu$ and i hadn't realised that it is a geometric.